# How do I properly assign variables for looping over in a php template, in php8.2

Tags: php

I am trying something as simple as displaying 5 articles in a php template. With the code I have I am able to display the 5 articles, but I also get 5 headers and 5 footers. So what I really want is to send the data to the tamplate, and do a foreach loop there.

If I try to put a 'foreach data as item' loop it the template, I get 'undefined variable' what ever i call the array of properties.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Here is what I have:

```
function archive() {
   $tpl = new Template();
  // setting PDO to use buffered queries in mysql is
  // important if you plan on using multiple result cursors
  // in the template.
  $db = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD , array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
     
  $results = $db->prepare("select * from articles");
  $results->execute();
  
  // assign to smarty

  $tpl->pageTitle="Arkiv";
  while($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $tpl->properties['id'] = $row["id"];
  $tpl->properties['title'] = $row["title"];
  $tpl->properties['publicationDate'] = $row["publicationDate"];
  $tpl->properties['summary'] = $row["summary"];
  $tpl->properties['content'] = $row["content"];
  $tpl->properties['image'] = $row["image"];
  echo $tpl->render('/archive2.tpl');
}
}
```

And here is my template:

```
<?php include 'header.tpl'; ?>
     <article>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
             <h1><?=$this->title;?></h1><br><?=$this->publicationDate;?>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
             <img src="images/<?=$this->image;?>" class="img-responsive" />
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <?=$this->summary;?>
            <?=$this->content;?>
        
        <button class="btn btn-success" style="float: right;" onClick="location.href='.?action=viewArticle&amp;articleId=<?=$this->id;?>'">Les mer...</button>
</div> 
</div>
</article>
<?php include 'footer.tpl';?>
```

And here is an attempt without the while condition, that I used in the attempt to loop in the template

```
function archive() {
   $tpl = new Template();
  // setting PDO to use buffered queries in mysql is
  // important if you plan on using multiple result cursors
  // in the template.
  $db = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD , array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
     
  $results = $db->prepare("select * from articles");
  $results->execute();
  
  // assign to smarty

  $tpl->pageTitle=" Arkiv";
  $row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  $tpl->properties['id'] = $row["id"];
  $tpl->properties['title'] = $row["title"];
  $tpl->properties['publicationDate'] = $row["publicationDate"];
  $tpl->properties['summary'] = $row["summary"];
  $tpl->properties['content'] = $row["content"];
  $tpl->properties['image'] = $row["image"];
  echo $tpl->render('/archive.tpl');
}
```

And here is the template class:

```
    class Template {
  private $_scriptPath=TEMPLATE_PATH;//comes from config.php
  public $properties;
  public function setScriptPath($scriptPath){
    $this->_scriptPath=$scriptPath;
  }
  public function __construct(){
      $this->properties = array();
  }
  public function render($filename){

   ob_start();
   if(file_exists($this->_scriptPath.$filename)){
     include($this->_scriptPath.$filename);
    } else throw new TemplateNotFoundException();
    return ob_get_clean();
  }
  public function __set($k, $v){
      $this->properties[$k] = $v;
  }
  public function __get($k){
      return $this->properties[$k];
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `Template`, framework?

Comment: I added the template class

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main question is: why try to emulate *smarty*?

However your system can also work.
To display more than one row you can insert a loop in your template, but you have to pass an array of data to it.

So in your function *archive* you can read the data (I suggest you to use mode PDO::FETCH_OBJ) and then pass it to your template:

```
$results = $db->prepare('select * from articles');
$results->execute();
$rows = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); // let's get it all

$tpl->properties['rows'] = $rows; // here we assign all the rows to the template
```

Your template will look something like this:

```
<?php include 'header.tpl'; ?>

<article>

    <?php foreach ($this->rows as $row): ?>

        <div class="row">
    
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1> <?= $row->title ?> </h1>
                <br> 
                <?= $row->publicationDate ?>
            </div>      
            
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="images/<?= $row->image ?>" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <?= $row->summary ?>
                <?= $row->content ?>

                <button class="btn btn-success" style="float: right;" 
                        onClick="location.href='.?action=viewArticle&amp;articleId=<?= $row->id ?>'"
                >
                    Les mer...
                </button>
            
            </div> 

        </div>
        
    <?php endforeach; ?>
        
</article>

<?php include 'footer.tpl';?>
```

You must keep in mind that:

- The rows of data are now few, when you have many you will have to build a pagination system
- Since PHP 8.2 dynamic properties are deprecated, so you will need to define the *pageTitle* property in your *Template* class

Comment: Thank you SOOO much!!! Your soluition worked petfect. At first I tried with just 'foreach $rows as $row', and I got the same 'Undefined variable $rows in template', like I got in about 100 different attempts before. The 'foreach $this->rows as $row' was the difference. The reason for trying php templates instead of smarty is that I wanted to understand whats happening. Smarty is way to big and complex for me. I'm not smart enough for smarty. :) Thanks once again!